# Do we have to change the bundle identifier and package name for a flutter if it is the form com.example.company?

Tags: flutter, firebase, bundle-identifier, package-name

I was just wondering before I use the google maps api or even publish my app, if I should change my bundle identifier and package name for my flutter app. My bundle identifier and package name both in the form of com.example.company_Name. The reason I ask is because I've seen people recommend to change this as it is a placeholder, but does not changing it affect the app in the future?

Also, if the recommendation is to change, if I'm using flutter in VSCode, do I have to change the bundle identifier in Xcode and the package name in Android Studio, or is there an easier way to do this?

Thanks!

I've tried changing the bundle identifier and package name in VSCode, but it didn't work, so I'm just wondering if it is worth trying again.

Answer (score 0):

If your application does not exist, you can use the following command to set the bundle ID for the app when create:

> flutter create --org <com.yourdomain>

If your application already exists: You can use the following package to change it more easily
[change_app_package_name](https://pub.dev/packages/change_app_package_name) and use the following command:

> flutter pub run change_app_package_name:main com.new.package.name